# Solr - Multiple types for the same field

Tags: solr

Is it possible to have a field in `schema.xml` that is of type `text_fr` or `text_ar`, because this field can be in french or in arabic?

Or should I regroup the definitions of `text_fr` or `text_ar` in the same custom type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Copyfields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) to copy the source to multiple fields with different anaylysis.

Also,

```
<copyField source="text" dest="text_fr" />
<copyField source="text" dest="text_ar" />
```

Comment: That's smart & simple. I will stick to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [Language Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) support that Solr provides.

> This feature adds the ability to detect the language of a document before indexing and then make appropriate decisions about analysis, etc.

A little bit better description of this support and a comparison of the two supported detection types can be found in [Solr Reference Guide - Detecting Languages During Indexing](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing)

Comment: It seems as complicated solution for me as a beginner but I will check it later, when I will master Solr better.